# Tidyeval in own functions inside own functions with the pipe

Tags: r, tidyverse, devtools, rlang, tidyeval

So I am trying to make a package (I have not included my roxygen2 headers below):

I have this function:

```
date_from_text <- function(df, x){
  x <- rlang::enquo(x)
  name <- rlang::quo_name(x)

  df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(!!name := lubridate::ymd_hms(!!x))
}
```

And when the datetime column has the right class then I use this to extract all the component.

```
date_columns <- function(df, x){

  x <- rlang::enquo(x)

  df %>%
      dplyr::mutate(year=lubridate::year(!!x),
           ydag=lubridate::yday(!!x),
           weekday=lubridate::wday(!!x, label=FALSE),
           hour = lubridate::hour(!!x),
           hour_min= hms::as.hms(lubridate::force_tz(!!x)),
           week_num = lubridate::week(!!x),
           month = lubridate::month(!!x),
           date = lubridate::date(!!x))
}
```

I don't wnat the `date_from_text` function to be included in the `NAMESPACE` and I want to include it somehow in the `date_columns` function. Something like checking if the timestamp has the right class and if not then change the class.. and then create all the datetime components.

I don't know how to call the first function inside the other function.

data for testing :

```
df <- structure(list(time = c("2018-01-30 20:08:18", "2018-02-01 21:01:25", 
"2018-01-31 23:25:12", "2018-01-28 23:45:34", "2018-01-31 12:00:55", 
"2018-02-04 09:15:31", "2018-01-27 21:08:02", "2018-02-08 01:50:31", 
"2018-02-01 03:15:43", "2018-02-04 01:04:52"), type = c("A", 
"D", "B", "B", "B", "D", "C", "C", "C", "A")), .Names = c("time", 
"type"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

UPDATE: So I have now included `date_from_text` into the `date_columns`

```
date_columns <- function(df, x){
  x <- rlang::enquo(x)

  out <-  df %>%
    date_from_text(!!x) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(year=lubridate::year(!!x),
           ydag=lubridate::yday(!!x),
           weekday=lubridate::wday(!!x, label=FALSE),
           hour = lubridate::hour(!!x),
           hour_min= hms::as.hms(lubridate::force_tz(!!x)),
           week_num = lubridate::week(!!x),
           month = lubridate::month(!!x),
           date = lubridate::date(!!x))
 out

  }
```

So I don't understand why I have to use `!!x` again inside `date_columns`?? It is already included inside `date_from_text`. I am calling the function not creating it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192598/discussion-between-david-and-hplieninger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As worked out in comments and chat, the question is neither about package development and namespaces nor about the pipe. The question is how to use [tidyeval](/questions/tagged/tidyeval) in possibly nested wrapper functions.

The answer is that expressions as passed by the user to the function need to be [quoted and unquoted](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/sec-up-to-speed.html#quote-and-unquote), just as in `date_from_text()` below via `enquo(x)` and `!!x`.

```r
date_from_text <- function(df, x) {
        x <- rlang::enquo(x)                                  # quote via enquo()
        name <- rlang::quo_name(x) 
        dplyr::mutate(df, !!name := lubridate::ymd_hms(!!x))  # unquote via !!
}
```

Then, expressions can be passed to such functions in "interactive" mode, just like dplyr functions:

```r
date_from_text(df, time)
select(df, time)
```

Remember that **functions inside functions** don't take expressions, but expressions that are quoted and unquoted, just like in the `mutate()` call with `enquo(x)` and `!!x` above.

This means, that, in `date_from_text()` below, both the call `date_from_text()` and `mutate()` need to receive `!!x`.

```r
date_columns <- function(df, x) {
        x <- rlang::enquo(x)

        out <- date_from_text(df, !!x)
        out <- dplyr::mutate(out, year = lubridate::year(!!x))
        return(out)
}
```

Apart from that, in package development, you can use all of your functions whether they are [exported](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#exports) or not (as I did with `date_from_text()` inside `date_columns()`). Exported functions need to be documented and can be used after installation via `library(pkg)` or `pkg::fun()`, whereas unexported functions can only be used after installation via `pkg:::fun()`.

*I modified @David's functions in order to focus on the relevant parts*.